# How can I catch a SERVFAIL exception using Python's dns resolver?

Tags: python-3.x, exception, dns

I'm looking to query a domain like this:

```
dns.resolver.resolve("dnssec-failed.org","A")
```

Which returns an error like this:

```
 raise NoNameservers(request=self.request, errors=self.errors)
dns.resolver.NoNameservers: All nameservers failed to answer the query dnssec-failed.org. IN A: Server 127.0.0.1 UDP port 53 answered SERVFAIL
```

I want to be able to catch that exception in my function like so:

```
def get_a_record(url):
    try:
        answers = dns.resolver.resolve(url,"A")
    except dns.resolver.SERVFAIL:
        print("SERVFAIL error for %s" % url)
    except dns.resolver.NXDOMAIN:
        print("No such domain %s" % url)
    except dns.resolver.Timeout:
        print("Timed out while resolving %s" % url)
    except dns.exception.DNSException:
        print("Unhandled exception")
```

Now I know in the above snippet dns resolver doesn't have a SERVAIL exception but what I'd like to do is catch the error, be able to log it, and continue my script. Is there a proper way to do this using the dns resolver package, or would I need to call the `dig` command and parse that result?

**EDIT**

For clarification, I only used dnssec-failed.org as an example because it results in (what I thought) would be the same response as something I am specifically looking, for but don't actually have any active examples of. That "something" being domains which point to ip addresses that are no longer in use. Dangling NS records in other words.

For example I use an IP address that is loaned to me by AWS for use in some XYZ cloud-based application, and I create the name-to-address mapping records in my DNS zone. If I decide to deprecate this service and return the ip back to the cloud provider's pool of ips but forget to remove the DNS record from the zone, it is left "dangling".

That is what I am looking for and I mistakenly assumed that a SERVFAIL is the type of response I get from a query like `dig domain-with-no-ip.com`
Apologies for the confusion.

**EDIT 2**

I went and tested this by taking a domain I'd already registered. Configured an A record for it and pointed it to an Ubuntu EC2 listening on port 7272 (python3 -m http.server 7272). Waited 5 minutes for the zone to propagate and then I was able to reach my domain, publicly. All fine and good.

Then I stopped the instance, waited a bit, and then restarted it. Upon coming back up it had a new public ip. Great. So at this point there is a dangling A record for me to test.

So I do dig and nslookup on the domain. Both come back with perfectly fine answers. They just simply point to the now old/original public ip. And that makes sense since the DNS record hasn't changed. The only observable thing that really changes is something like curl, which times out.

So unless my understanding is still wrong, there really isn't an all-too reliable way to hunt down dangling A records because basing logic off n http timeout doesn't necessarily imply a dangling record. The server could just be off/down and the ip is still attached to the resource. Am I correct in my understanding or am I missing something still?

**EDIT 3**

Accepting the answer because even though my question mildly evolved into something else, the answer did technically address the original question of my post and I think that warrants accepting it.

Comment: The exception is `dns.resolver.NoNameservers`. This link provides the exception hierarchy: https://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.15.0/dns.resolver.NoNameservers-class.html Documentation: https://dnspython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/exceptions.html#dns.resolver.NoNameservers Some examples catching that exception: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97693/dns.resolver.NoNameservers

Comment: @JohnHanley the problem is more complex than that. This domain HAS nameservers, but fails DNSSEC validation hence the error. Try `dig dnssec-failed.org NS` towards a recursive nameserver that does DNSSEC validation and you get `SERVFAIL` as expected, but add `+cdflag` to disable DNSSEC processing and you compeltely get the nameservers: `dns101.comcast.net.` to `dns105.comcast.net.`

Comment: Do you need any kind of specific treatment for DNSSEC or just go over it (bad idea in general, but no details really in your questiom)? In the later case, just make sure to use a non validating resolver or add the necessary option in query to disable validation and then you are guaranteed to not get exceptions just because of DNSSEC failures. In any case, do not parse the output of `dig` this is a tool intended for human consumption not to have its output be parsed... even if newer versions have a `--yaml` option for the output ;-)

Comment: 1) I was just helping you create the correct exception handler which is completely different from a strategy to handle DNSSEC failures.  2) Any domain that has DNSSEC enabled and activated but fails to validate is not trustworthy. 3) There are two general reasons: a) an actual security failure such as a compromise or b) misconfiguration.

Comment: 4) I do not recommend disabling validation. Instead, consider the domain compromised and move on. Any data returned where you bypass validation is not trustworthy - "garbage in, garbage out". There are exceptions of course such as writing tools to check for DNSSEC problems.

Comment: 1) you seem to not have read the exception message... NoNameServers in this case exactly happens because of a SERVFAIL and, obviously here for this domain because of DNSSEC failure (but other cases can create SERVFAIL). 2) yes, in theory, but a) this is absolutely not the question here and b) it is not clear what parent wants to do there about DNSSC. 4) you didn't understand what I said, wait for my answer below then. "such as writing tools to check for DNSSEC problems. " and how do you know this is not what the OP is doing? So you are commenting besides the point here.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek - The question is `How can I catch a SERVFAIL exception using Python's dns resolver?` and not how to analyze or handle DNSSEC validation. I did not post an answer, I posted a comment. When I posted the follow-on comments, I did not pay attention that you were not the person who posted the question.

Comment: "The question is How can I catch a SERVFAIL exception using Python's dns resolver? and not how to analyze or handle DNSSEC validation. " My answer explains why this is not possible to achieve in the constraints given as `resolve()` is a too high API for this kind of problems, it doesn't necessarily expose the low level (and I am sure you know that `SERVFAIL` was designed for DNSSEC failures because there is no other way possible, but the current trend is clearly to have separate errors - at the DNS level - for DNSSEC failures), and I show how to do it if one is interested by DNSSEC errors.

Comment: I used dnssec-failed.org as an example because it results in the same response as something I am looking, for but don't have any active examples of. That "something" being domains which point to ip addresses that are no longer in use. Dangling NS records in other words. For example I use an IP address that is loaned to me by AWS for use in some XYZ cloud-based application, and I create the name-to-address mapping records in my DNS zone. If I decide to deprecate this service and return the ip back to the cloud provider but forget to remove the DNS record from the zone, it is left "dangling".

Comment: Your example of a "dangling" DNS record will not generate a DNSSEC error. I am not sure how that applies to your question about how to catch a SERVFAIL exception.

Comment: Ahh so my understanding was that if I were to do something like "dig <domain-with-no-ip.com>" that it would result in a SERVFAIL because there would be no HTTP response to actually parse. If that is wrong then I need to step back and first figure *what* sort of response I'd actually get so I can look for that instead. Do you know what result I should expect in this case of requesting a domain with a dangling NS record? Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: A DNS server will just return whatever value you set for the DNS resource record. The DNS server does not validate that the record points to a real computer or IP address. If you have a domain and DNS server, create a few bogus entries and test.

Comment: Alright, I went and verified. You're right, I don't get a servfail from dig when the underlying ip has changed so I can't actually base any logic off of that. The answer comes back perfectly fine. Made a second edit to my original post with some details.

Comment: After your Edit 2. Correct. Also, consider that a DNS record could be pointing to a resource that is behind a firewall only allowing certain networks to access the resource. DNS is like a big phone book. Just because there is a phone number published does not mean you still live there or will answer the door bell or are able to answer the phone right now.

Comment: " if I were to do something like "dig <domain-with-no-ip.com>" that it would result in a SERVFAIL because there would be no HTTP response to actually parse. " It is not clear what "domain with no IP means".  If you register a domain but do not attach nameserver to it, the parent won't publish NS records for it and hence queries will return NXDOMAIN (this is  a legit situation, many domains are like that). If there are nameservers but no A record at apex you get "NODATA" aka NOERROR + no answer (as there will be SOA/NS records just no A). Also the protocol used by DNS is not HTTP :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "domain with no IP"? Spend some time studying DNS. A DNS Server does not care what records you have or do not have. Besides the SOA and NS, a DNS server requires no other records. A SERVFAIL means there was an error, not that a record does not exist which is NODATA. Note: create a new question when you have a question. Comments are to help improve the question, not to chat or provide answers.

Comment: domain-with-no-ip.com was my poorly-worded way of saying a domain that was assigned an ip address (think EC2 instance getting an EIP) and a dns zone to that maps the domain to that ip (think Route53). And then later on, that EIP is released back into the pool while the dns record remains. So as far as DNS goes, yes the domain has an ip but now the ip is either unused, or tied to a new, unrelated, resource.

Comment: Like I said in my edit, what I am actually looking for has diverged from my original post (thanks to the clarification from both of you). So I think it's fair to say that the comments did enhance the original post. I just didn't want the help from your comments to go unrewarded. Again, to be pedantic, my new question is "how to identify dangling NS records" and I think that no longer aligns with what I asked originally because I misunderstood servfail responses as being a means to catch dangling NS records when in fact they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `dnssec-failed.org` has nameservers but is, by design, failing DNSSEC.

Hence a simple query towards any recursive nameserver that does DNSSEC validation will fail with `SERVFAIL` as expected:

```
$ dig dnssec-failed.org NS +short
(no output)
$ dig dnssec-failed.org NS | grep status: | tail -1
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 46517
```

but as soon as you disable DNSSEC validation you get the nameservers as it should be:

```
$ dig dnssec-failed.org NS +cdflag +noall +ans +nottlunits
dnssec-failed.org.  7200 IN NS dns105.comcast.net.
dnssec-failed.org.  7200 IN NS dns101.comcast.net.
dnssec-failed.org.  7200 IN NS dns102.comcast.net.
dnssec-failed.org.  7200 IN NS dns103.comcast.net.
dnssec-failed.org.  7200 IN NS dns104.comcast.net.
```

Now back to the Python part.

`resolve()` from dnspython is an high level API call, it does everything a resolver does, that is it potentially recurse from root up to being able to give you an answer. Hence, this simple call hides possibly multiple questions and responses and as such may not expose you to the real underlying problem, but provides high level API in output also, using an exception.

As you can see in your own example, you have the `SERVFAIL` right in the error message, but it is an `NoNameservers` exceptions because the code asked the registry nameservers for the list of nameservers (which works, there is a DS for this name in parent nameservers), and then ask for any of those nameservers for further data and then they fail there DNSSEC validation, hence the final exception.

It is not clear to me what is your position on DNSSEC error in your case, if you do not care about them or if you really want to study them and do something particular. Hence the above solutions may need to be adapted. If you do not care, just log the `NoNameservers` exception and go on, everything will work as excepted, DNSSEC validation error will happen exactly like a broken domain, which is per design.

Hence do you really need to handle DNSSEC errors in any way different from any other errors? Why can't you catch `NoNameservers` exception, log it, and go further?

Otherwise the quick (and dirty way), just parse the error message attached to the `NoNameservers` exception, and if you see `SERVFAIL` you can suppose (but not be 100% sure) it is a DNSSEC problem, and at least go further as you need.

If you really need to have further details and be sure it is a DNSSEC problem, you need to do the equivalent of what is above for `dig`, that is do 2 queries that just differ in the `CD` DNS flag, and compare results. Which means going "lower" than `resolve()` API and use `dns.query` directly, such as this way:

```
>>> import dns, dns.rcode
>>> resolver_ip = '8.8.8.8'   # Use any recursive **validating** nameserver that you trust
>>> query=dns.message.make_query('dnssec-failed.org', 'A')
>>> response = dns.query.udp_with_fallback(query, resolver_ip)[0]
>>> response.rcode() == dns.rcode.SERVFAIL
True

# Now checking if disabling DNSSEC resolves the problem and gets us a reply
# If so, it really means there is a DNSSEC problem

>>> print(str(query))
id 65008
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags RD
;QUESTION
dnssec-failed.org. IN A
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
>>> query.flags
<Flag.RD: 256>
>>> query.flags = query.flags | dns.flags.CD
>>> query.flags
<Flag.RD|CD: 272>
>>> print(str(query))
id 65008
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags RD CD
;QUESTION
dnssec-failed.org. IN A
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL

# We enabled flag "CD" aka checking disabled aka please do not do any DNSSEC validation, and now doing the same query as above again:

>>> response = dns.query.udp_with_fallback(query, resolver_ip)[0]
>>> response.rcode() == dns.rcode.SERVFAIL
False
>>> response.rcode() == dns.rcode.NOERROR
True
>>> response.answer[0][0]
<DNS IN A rdata: 69.252.80.75>
```